# What plugins are necessary for Play Framework 2 for intellij (and how to install)

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I am unable to install Java Play Framework Support for Play 2 in intellij ultimate 2016.2.4. I'm not sure if I really need it. I have the Scala plugin which says it has Play 2 Support. I see all kinds of conflicting documentation.

I had the Playframework Support for Play 1 but unchecked that. When I search for Play 2 plugin I get nothing. I downloaded it directly but was unable to install from disk. The download has a directory scala-play-2 so, again, I'm not sure if this is the plugin I already have. When I click on 2 of the jars, sbt-launch and  scala-play-2-jps-plugin.jar, it says "fail to locate plugin descriptor". When I click scala-play-2.jar it says "Plun play 2.0 support is incompatible with this installation'.

I right click my project to add framework support. I see the Play 2.x framework is unchecked. When I check and enter it does nothing. Not sure if this is related but in the Framework Support dialog it has a select for Java EE version. It only goes to Java EE 7. My project and platform settings are set to jdk 1.8.

If someone has a current working configuration I sure would like to know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have scala plugin, the problem should be you have to install [sbt](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/5007-sbt) plugin.

- Go to settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories. And search for ***sbt*** plugin. Then you can install. :))

Comment: Does this mean we no longer need the Java Play plugin, just the Scala plugin? This seems to be a moving target as many other posts mention a separate java play plugin. The instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html are also confusing. The say: In the left-hand pane, select Scala.
Note that for creating a Java project with the Play 2.x framework, you need to select Java.
But when you select java, you get totally different choices. If you select play after it, you get a pretty empty project.

Comment: @user6627139 can you pls upload the screen-shots regarding your problem (framework selection)?? Then it would be much easier to inspect what's gone wrong. :))